# Robots.txt and sitemaps

Tags: seo, google, sitemap, robots.txt

If i where to block a web page, say 404Error.aspx, in robots,txt (i see no reason for this page to be indexed by google). However, do i still include this page in the xml sitemap or not?

Edit:

If i wanted my page to be indexed (google follows the links in it), but not show up in search results, should i remove robots.txt and use the robots meta tag with "noindex" ?

Comment: How does the page `404Error.aspx` ever get indexed? You shouldn't be redirecting to that page if there is a 404 error...

Comment: 404Error is a page i use to replace the default 404 error. I want it to be crawled as it contains links back to the homepage but i don't want it indexed for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i wanted my page to be indexed (google follows the links in it),
>   but not show up in search results, should i remove robots.txt and use
>   the robots meta tag with "noindex" ?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop Google and the other Search Engines to have in their index this page, I see no reason to have the link in the sitemap too. You should have the link only in your robots.txt

Comment: Thats what i tought but i wanted to be sure, thanks friend

Comment: @TheGateKeeper Glad to help you ;)

Comment: I edited the question, please have a look